# Criando um jogo de questionário, como evito duplicação de código em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um jogo simples de selecionar a resposta correta, a estrutura básica está funcionando, mas gostaria de melhorar o meu código, e aprender a fatorizar melhor.

Segue o trecho que definem as variáveis que uso:

```js
let pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, 
chB, chC, chD, chE, chF, chG, chH, chI, correct = 0, wrong = 0;

let questions = [
{
        question: "Qual dos dois filmes se refere a 'Jornada nas Estrelas'?",
        a: "Star Trek",
        b: "Star Wars",
        c: "ambas as respostas estāo corretas",
        d: "ambas as respostas estão incorretas",
        answer: "A"
},
{
        question: "A frase icônica: 'You bow to no one my friends', foi dito por qual personagem?",
        a: "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        b: "Gandalf",
        c: "Tex Willer",
        d: "Aragorn",
        e: "Capitāo America",
        f: "Spock",
        g: "Nenhuma das opções acima",
        answer: "D"
}
```

E aqui o código relevante a minha pergunta:

```js
    question = questions[pos].question;
    chA = questions[pos].a;
    chB = questions[pos].b;
    chC = questions[pos].c;
    chD = questions[pos].d;
    chE = questions[pos].e;
    chF = questions[pos].f;
    chG = questions[pos].g;
    chH = questions[pos].h;
    chI = questions[pos].i;

    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";

    test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "</label><br>";
    if (typeof chB !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "</label><br>";
    if (typeof chC !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"</label><br>";
    if (typeof chD !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "</label><br>";
    if (typeof chE !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='E'> "+chE+"</label><br>";
    if (typeof chF !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='F'> "+chF+"</label><br>";
    if (typeof chG !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='G'> "+chG+"</label><br>";
    if (typeof chH !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='H'> "+chH+"</label><br>";
    if (typeof chI !== "undefined")
        test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='I'> "+chI+"</label><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<label></label><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Confirmar Resposta</button>";
```

O meu editor de texto reclama de duplicação de código tanto na inicialização das variáveis `chA, chB ... chI` como na parte que crio o elemento botao no HTML (`innerHTML...`). Minha pergunta é, como devo proceder pra eliminar esse emaranhado de código repetitivo, e por tudo num loop, por exemplo?

Um último detalhe:
preciso verificar toda vez se a variável em questão não é undefined para evitar o seguinte de ocorrer:

[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, 
    chB, chC, chD, chE, chF, chG, chH, chI, correct = 0, wrong = 0;

    let questions = [
    {
            question: "Qual dos dois filmes se refere a 'Jornada nas Estrelas'?",
            a: "Star Trek",
            b: "Star Wars",
            c: "ambas as respostas estāo corretas",
            d: "ambas as respostas estão incorretas",
            answer: "a"
    },
    {
            question: "A frase icônica: 'You bow to no one my friends', foi dito por qual personagem?",
            a: "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
            b: "Gandalf",
            c: "Tex Willer",
            d: "Aragorn",
            e: "Capitāo America",
            f: "Spock",
            g: "Nenhuma das opções acima",
            answer: "d"
    }]

    let code = '';
    questions.forEach(function(v, i) {
        code += '<div data-q="'+i+'">'
        code += '<h4>'+v.question+'</h4>'
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('a')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="a">' +v.a + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('b')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="b">' +v.b + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('c')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="c">' +v.c + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('d')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="d">' +v.d + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('e')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="e">' +v.e + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('f')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="f">' +v.f + '<p>' : '');
        code += ((questions[i].hasOwnProperty('g')) ? '<p><input class="quest" name="quest-'+i+'" type="radio" value="g">' +v.g + '<p>' : '');
        code += '</div>';
    })

let result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerHTML = code;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Impressionante, nao conhecia JQUERY, vou estudá-lo para entender como seu código está funcionando, você tem alguma sugestão de literatura?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: https://jquery.com/

Comment: @Pirategull, a solução do Rodrigo foi útil pra você. Mas não aconselho focar muito no jQuery, já que parou de receber atualizações e em breve ficará meio que "obsoleto", restando só os sistemas legados com jQuery. Aconselho estudar essa resposta dele e focar no JavaScript Vanilla. Tente passar essas resposta de jQuery para JavaScript Vanilla. É só uma opinião minha. Aconselho dar uma pesquisada melhor no jQuery hoje no mercado.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, eu assumi que a maneira correta era usando essa library, então existe uma maneira de fazer isso em javascript puro?

Comment: Se jQuery é feito em JavaScript, sim, é claro que pode se fazer com JavaScript puro. Há _anos_, quando a web ainda estava em seus "primeiros passos", o jQuery era justificável para contornar a falta de compatibilidade entre os _browsers_. Hoje, conforme o @GatodeSchrödinger mencionou, não é mais tão necessário. O JavaScript e os navegadores foram propriamente padronizados. Não existe "certo" ou "errado", mas se você quiser realmente aprender JavaScript (que é um dos três pilares do front-end), não deve ir pelo jQuery, mas sim pelo JS "puro". Já foi ruim, mas hoje, indubitavelmente melhor.

Comment: Fiz a edição para javascript puro.

Comment: Show de bola, @RodrigoZem.

Comment: Eu comecei a aprender pelo jQuery e chegou uma época que eu fiquei completamente dependente do jQuery a ponto de não saber fazer a mesma coisa que eu fazia em jQuery no JS "Puro". Por isso, indico pra quem está começando a iniciar pelo JS vanilla. Para depois, não passar pelo que eu passei. Não que não precise estudar jQuery, mas é só pra não ficar dependente.

Comment: Pra ajudar na transição jQuery -> JS puro: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/